# FIR Filter Transition Coefficient

Tags: filter, frequency, fir

Design a length L=40 linear-phase FIR filter using frequency sampling design with an optimum approach. Use the transiton coefficient table given in Proakis and Manolakis.

[image: Transition coefficient table]

My M is 39, how can I use this table for M=39?

Comment: Just a reference for when people wondering about your source... Appearing Purdue has a PDF copy of this book online [HERE](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ee538/DSP_Text_3rdEdition.pdf) but this link has a different location of where this table can be found. This table can be found under Appendix C, Table C.1.

Comment: I received a little context of what this table is even talking about. By the looks of it, it's referring to some type of minimax, which indicates a worse case scenario for trying to find the highest minimum value to prevent data loss. Going back to chapter 8 of this link I provided, it mentions a Chebyshev approximation that is applied to the (what the textbook calls) "Alternation Theorem" and it could be what you're looking for. Forgive me, I really don't know anything about this but this is just something I found by looking around and I suggest you to try the same.

Comment: This is one of the few books I actually sold back, because I thought it was useless

Comment: Why do you choose M that is not a power of 2? (POT)